# Do Google rich cards support webp video thumbnails?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, rich-cards

I addded some tags for VideoObject from http://schema.org/VideoObject, i use the same tags that similar websites use. I also tested it on https://search.google.com/test/rich-results, it said that my page is eligible for rich results, but google don't display the cards in the search results.

In the `thumbnailUrl` I put webp image, is it supported?

This is the tags that I use:

```
<div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
  <h1 itemprop="name">How to...</h1>
  <meta itemprop="duration" content="T10M20S">
  <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="https://example.com/image.webp">
  <meta itemprop="contentURL" content="https://example.com/video">
  <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="'2020-1-3T13:50:37-00:00">
  <meta itemprop="description" content="A video about something">

  <video src="../video.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification from Google

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video

Says:

Images must be in .jpg, .png, or. gif format

So I think the answer is no.